# How to bind a list of comma separated values to a Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In my asp.net mvc app I have a create view where I need to select a list of companies, so I have this:

```
@{
   var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
   var empresas = unitOfWork.EmpresaRepository.Get();
 }
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Empresa", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.ListBox("Empresa", new SelectList(empresas, "Id", "Nombre"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
   </div>
```

Basically I select all companies from my repository and then I render them on a list box, when I hit Save the selected companies are saved as a comma separated list of IDS, check formcollection

```
 //Setting extended property lookup name
 var extPropLookupName = $"extension_{SettingsHelper.ClientId.Replace("-", "")}_{"Compania"}";

 //TO BE FINISHED
 user.SetExtendedProperty(extPropLookupName, formCollection["Empresa"]);
 await user.UpdateAsync();
```

Now I am trying to implement the EDIT view.
so I know how to get the comma separated list, I also know how to get the list of companies, but the ListBox should show which are the SELECTED companies.

```
@{
   var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
   var empresas = unitOfWork.EmpresaRepository.Get();
   var keyvaluepair = Model.GetExtendedProperties().Where(prop => prop.Key == extPropLookupName).FirstOrDefault();
   if (keyvaluepair.Value != null)
   {
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Empresa", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

     <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.ListBox("Empresa", new SelectList(empresas, "Id", "Nombre"),  new { @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
   </div>
   }
}
```

Right now it renders the list of companies but with none selected, I know keyvaluepair.Value will have "1,2,3".

How can I bind that to the listbox so that it renders the selected items?

Comment: could you try to correct the formatting?

Comment: I gotta ask, why are you hitting your repository directly from the view instead of having the controller populate a model?  If you had a model, you could use `ListBoxFor()` to bind the selected values.  This way, you will likely need to construct the list box manually using a for loop because `ListBox()` has no facility to bind to selected values.

Comment: @PaulAbbott that is not possible the model in this sample is an Active DIrectory User, not something in Entity Framework, and the extended properties(schema extensions) is the only way to save custom data into a User, in my case I want to save the IDS of the companies a user belongs to and I save it with comma separated list of IDs, thats the reason it cant be directly tied to a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backing makes no difference, you can still utilize a view model to work with the data in a strongly typed way. Just create a class that has properties to represent what you want to work with in AD, and then map your AD values to/from this class.

Then, you can do something like the following:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    ...

    public List<string> SelectedCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

In your action:

```
var model = new UserViewModel
{
    ...

    SelectedCompanies = user.GetExtendedProperty(extPropLookupName).Split(',')
}
```

And after post:

```
user.SetExtendedProperty(extPropLookupName, string.Join(",", model.SelectedCompanies);
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCompanies, new SelectList(empresas, "Id", "Nombre"),  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: before setting this as an answer, I tried that on the create form, and I have the following problem, could you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792622/viewmodel-instance-is-null-on-creating

Comment: Remove the `Bind` attribute. In particular, when using `Bind` you must pass the fully resolved property name, as it would be in your actual form, i.e. `Usario.UserPrincipalName` rather than `UserPrincipalName`, and likewise for each of the properties. However, `Bind` little more than a great way to introduce subtle errors into your application. If you want to restrict which values can and can't be edited, either include or don't include them on your view model. That's one of the main purposes of a view model, in the first place.